# Ezpublish: Search locations by Criterion\Location\Depth does not work

Tags: php, ezpublish

I have Ezpublish Community Project 2014.7
I am trying to make this code works:

```
    $criteria = array(
      new Criterion\Subtree( '/2/' ),
      new Criterion\Location\Depth( Criterion\Operator::BETWEEN,  array(0, 100) ),
    );

    $query = new LocationQuery(
    array(
      'criterion' => new Criterion\LogicalAnd( $criteria ),
      'sortClauses' => array( new SortClause\Location\Priority( Query::SORT_ASC ) )
      )
    );
    $query->limit = 3;
    $query->offset = 0;

    $result = $searchService->findLocations( $query );
```

It just does not return any results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your query its messy. I clean up and move `LogicalAnd` to variable `query`. Your code should look like:

```
$query = new LocationQuery();
$query->query = new Criterion\LogicalAnd(
    array(
        new Criterion\Subtree( '/2/' ),
        new Criterion\Location\Depth( Criterion\Operator::BETWEEN,  array(0, 100) )
    )
);
$query->sortClauses = array( new Query\SortClause\Location\Priority( Query::SORT_ASC ) );
$query->limit = 3;
$query->offset = 0;

$result = $this->searchService->findLocations( $query );
```